# replacement for EntityCollection Class from bing map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm migrating from bing map to Google map, while migrating got one class from bing map as Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection which Contains a collection of entities. An Entity can be any one of the following types: Infobox, Polygon, Polyline, Pushpin etc.

is there any support in  Google maps which will allow such functionality.

Comment: These are all overlays, but there is no overarching class in the Google Maps API.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: You could roll your own, I suppose; but I fail to see the point. When you convert your code, use the correct overlay object. It's a native object in its own right, rather than a class member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no as such EntityCollection in Google map. We can use overlays if we want to work with different markers